Get Response output is randomized, not Form field names
I have a requirement where a new Salesforce case must be created whenever a form in Microsoft Forms is filled and the filled form should be attached to the respective Salesforce case. Everything's working but my only concern is, in the attached file, all the form questions are gibberish. For example, r8-----------------c. Answers are fine, but only the questions are in some random format.
This is my Power Automate Flow:

When a new response is submitted
Get Response Details
Compose
Create Record ( for cases)
Create Record ( for attachments)

